# Django Contact form not showing the sender

Tags: python, django

I create a contact form but unable to show the sender, **the sender and receiver** is same value of **admin@gmail.com**. Here is my settings.py, views.py and models.py.

settings.py

```
# Registration Notification
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

views.py

```
def contacView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()

    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            recipients = ['admin@gmail.com']

            try:
                send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          from_email,
                          recipients,
                          fail_silently=False,
                          )

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')

            return redirect('success')
```

models.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

But whe I try this the sender email showed in the console

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: what is content of from_mail, are you attempting to send mail as different user?

Comment: Yes, I send a different email but it's not working but in 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend', the email sender is showing